# Updating to Entity Framework 6.0.2, now I have a 6.0.1 folder created on every build - why?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, nuget

I just ran:

```
Update-Pacakge
```

From the good ol' nuget package manager console and, amongst other things, it updated Entity Framework from `6.0` to `6.0.2`.  Brilliant - I love a shiny new version.

Now, I went to commit the updated stuff to SVN and I noticed that in my local packages folder I have:

```
- EntityFramework.6.0.1
- EntityFramework.6.0.2
```

So I deleted the `EntityFramework.6.0.1` folder (just added the 6.0.2 folder), did a build, some tests, and a commit and thought all was good.

But then I looked in my local packages folder and would you believe it, that pesky `EntityFramework.6.0.1` folder re-appears whenever I do a build (going through `delete the folder, clean, rebuild` enough times to skirt dangerously close to the [definition of insanity](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/alberteins133991.html)).

OK, so maybe something still references the old version so I did a `find in files` from [sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and the result is thus:

```
Searching 4477 files for "EntityFramework.6.0.1"

0 matches across 0 files
```

Right, now I ask the experts what gives...

**Why is the `EntityFramework.6.0.1` folder re-appearing when I do a build (surely it just needs `EntityFramework.6.0.2`) and can I stop it?**

Comment: Right click on the solution and go to manage nuget packages. Check to see if there are any other projects in your solution that are referencing the older version. Is it possible that your Update-Package command only updated a single project?

Comment: Ahh, OK, thanks - I have 5 projects in the solution - 3 of them were updated to EF 6.0.2 and 1 was updated to 6.0.1 (1 doesn't reference entity framework at all) :-S  The manage dialogue you mention showed this to me - so that was the answer - if you make it such I'll tick you.  :-)  Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that there is a project in your solution that is still referencing the older version of Entity Framework.

Right click on your solution and click Manage NuGet packages. If there are two versions of Entity Framework you will see both of them listed. You can upgrade them from there, or go back to the command line and update that specific project.